# Reduce water pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I'm installing a drip irrigation system to my "garden" , some 6 plant pots, but not been successful so far due to the high water pressure.
Yes I know I can go buy a pressure regulator, but this will take out the fun.
So I'd like understand how using little of physics and a little ingenuity and of course little money, could I do simple water pressure reducer.

Answer (score 1):

the coolest pressure regulator I have seen is the simplest, and most fun: it is a rubber plug with a small hole through it, inserted into the piping of a drip system. High water pressure squeezes the plug, causing it to deform. This partially occludes the hole, increasing its flow resistance. low water pressure does not deform the plug so much, leaving the hole unobstructed, decreasing the flow resistance. Over a reasonable range of source pressures, this maintain flow rate almost constant! and it only costs a couple of dollars.

Comment: Cool I'l hsve it a try

Answer (score 0):

Feed a reservoir or tank which then supplies the drip system by gravity.

The supply can be controlled by a timer or, if you want it supplied permanently, a ball valve that stops it overflowing.

Comment: That is what I'm using so far.